# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' after installing phpmyadmin on ubuntu

Tags: php, sql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin on my ubuntu server following these steps here:

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04/

I installed apache, php, mysql following these steps:

https://vijayasankarn.wordpress.com/2017/01/17/setting-lamp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04-using-aws-ec2/

and when I goto login to http://myserver.com/phpmyadmin I get this error:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a step that is not in the links above?

I have tried this:

```
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

$ service mysql restart
```

and this

```
mysql -u root -p
use mysql;
update user set plugin="" where user='root';
flush privilege;
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM user WHERE user='root'; GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'r00tp@ssw0rd'; GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'r00tp@ssw0rd'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: try to call from terminal: `mysql_secure_installation`

Comment: Thank you @num8er your first solution worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error can be fixed, the following command will reconfigure your phpMyAdmin credentials to gain access to the MYSQL DB:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

/!\ This will provide few interactive menus that will allow you to reconfigure the phpMyAdmin package with NEW credentials /!\

But you could also reconfigure it manually :

1 - Log into mysql as root

```
mysql -u root -p
```

2 - Make sure 'phpmyadmin' user exists :

```
SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
```

3 - Switch to the appropriate MYSQL DB :

```
use phpmyadmin;
```

4 - Set new password for the phpmyadmin user

```
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('yourNewPassword') WHERE User='phpmyadmin';
```

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` works for me and resolved the `access denied` error

Answer (score 1):

sudo mysql -u root -p

USE mysql;

UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User ='root';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

exit;

sudo systemctl restart mysql

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that you have actually set the root password in MySQL.  You might find that when logged in as the root Linux user you can run
`mysql -u root -p`
and get access to your database no matter which password you specify, because the password hasn't actually been set.  Use
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; EXIT;`
to set your password, then try phpMyAdmin again.