# How to fix Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' when resetting password in terminal does not work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am not familiar with setting up a WebServer, so I watched [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHYh-m4iXw4) about how to use PHPMyAdmin and MySQL to begin.

I use macOS High Sierra.

Here is what I have done so far:

- sudo apachectl start
- sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
- remove # before #LoadModule php5…
- sudo apachectl restart
- sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
- Add index.php in DirectoryIndex line
- sudo apachectl restart
- sudo nano /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.php
- create Hello World php file at localhost
- download Mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/
- saved the password
- sudo mkdir /var/mysql
- sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
- Start mysql Server
- cd /usr/local/mysql/bin
- sudo ./mysql -u root -p
- Alter user ’root’@‘localhost identified by ‘newpassword’;
- Download phpmyadmin: https://www.phpmyadmin.net
- Copy paste it into Documents folder and rename to phpMyAdmin
- cd /Library/Webserver/Documents/
- cd phpMyAdmin
- sudo mkdir config
- sudo chmod o+x config
- open localhost/phpmyadmin
- Under Authentication, enter mysql password
- Download Config
- Copy/Paste config into config folder

I am wondering if the configuration file contains some error that has prevented me from success. The config.inc.php file is stored under *Macintosh HD **>** Library **>** WebServer **>** Documents **>** phpMyAdmin **>** config*. When I removed this file from the config folder and put it under the general phpMyAdmin folder, I had the same error message.

The server configuration within config.inc.php may be the problem.

```
    /* Servers configuration */
    $i = 0;

    /* Server: localhost -> 127.0.0.1 [1] */
    $i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost'; /* was previously = 'localhost'; */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
```

I expected to log in with username: root and password: password without any issues.

Instead, I get the error **mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

I looked up this issue on StackOverflow weeks ago, but it seems people who solved this problem were using XAMPP. Installing XAMPP could make matters worse, because I have already installed config.inc.php and the default settings are different from those that would come from XAMPP.

I have followed [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320095/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-after-installing-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu) on how to flush privileges and change the password to access MySQL, but my terminal does not recognize the commands. I get the error that there is no such command that exists.

Comment: I'm seeing `ALTER USER ... IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword'` doesn't seem to jive with  `$cfg[..][..]['password'] = 'password';`

Comment: @spencer7593 Very true. Should I alter ['password'] = 'newpassword' in the config.inc.php file? I tried this with no success in phpMyAdmin and the terminal.

Comment: I assume you are symlinking the socket for the `mysql` defaults (could just use `-S`)? Why not use the original socket path in your config.inc.php? Does `sudo -u {phpuser} mysql -u root -p{newpassword}` work?

Comment: My terminal gave the error "sudo: mysql: command not found". I must admit, I looked it up on wikipedia but I don't completely understand what symlinking and sockets/socket paths are. I think I understand  that /usr/local/mysql/bin is a symlink, but I'm not sure of the rest of what you said.
I looked up "symlink socket" and the results were not explaining the meaning, sorry.

Comment: if `mysql` is not found as a command, it means your $PATH variable does not include the directory where the `mysql` executable is found.  In a terminal, type `echo $PATH` to see that the current value is.  Not one of the directories listed here contain the mysql binary.   You need to find where it is.  You can do: `find / -name mysql -print` to find it.  Note, I do not have Mac to test, this is based on linux/unix knowledge.

Comment: My result from "find / -name mysql -print" returned so many "Permissions denied"/"Operation not permitted".  I did get the results "/Users/[username]/anaconda/pkgs/sqlalchemy-1.1.5-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql",
"/Users/[username]/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql","/usr/local/mysql-5.7.26-macos10.14-x86_64/bin/mysql"and "/usr/local/mysql-5.7.26-macos10.14-x86_64/include/mysql".

Comment: The command "echo $PATH" returns "/Users/[username]/.nvm/versions/node/v10.0.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/[username]/.fastlane/bin:/Users/[username]/anaconda/bin:/Users/[deleted user]/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS". 
I have no idea why the user I deleted from my computer shows up. Is my goal to make echo $PATH include a path to where mysql is on my machine? I'm not sure where to go from here.